# How do I change SQL Left Join to Lambda expression in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lambda

I have three tables and one input value. As a first step, based on the `@Input`, I need to fetch `DSType` from `DSTypes` table. Now again I need to compare `DSType` of `DSTypes` with `RTInput` table's `IType` column value. If `RTInput` table has matching records then need to fetch the `ID` column value alone otherwise `NULL` should be assigned.

I achieved this logic in SQL but unable to achieve the same in Lambda expression.
I tried some code from google but that is not returning correct value.

```
DECLARE @ID
@ID = SELECT ID FROM DSMaster Where DSTId = @Input

SELECT RTI.ID FROM DSTypes(NOLOCK) DST
LEFT JOIN RTInput(NOLOCK) RTI
ON RTRIM(LTRIM(DST.DSType)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(RTI.IType))
WHERE DST.ID = @ID
```

Lambda expression which I tried:

```
using (BEContext beContext = new BEContext())
{
var mData = beContext.DSMaster.Where(r => r.DSTId = inputvalue);
var Id = beContext.RTInput.Join(beContext.DSTypes.Where(dst => dst.ID == mData.Id )).Select(z => z.ID).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482709/c-sharp-left-outer-join-lambda-expression-error

Comment: Use left outer join.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: @jdweng - microsoft link has answer in LINQ format bit I need to convert the query to lambda expression.

Comment: Linq and Lambda are the same just a different format. I often combine both Linq and Lambda together.

Comment: @jdweng - I agree, but I need a solution as Lambda expression as it was a technique followed in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help.

```
using {BEContext beContext = new BEContext()){

var mData = (from p in beContext.DSMaster.Where(r=>r.DSTId == inputvalue)

join pr in beContext.RTInput on p.Id equals dst.ID

select new {

//select what you want


}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I need a solution as Lambda expression as it was a technique followed in my project.